# Is it possible to use a HTML5 audio tag attribute ID to track song plays in Google Anaylitics

Tags: google-analytics, html5-audio

I have seen several older responses to a similar question but am hoping that since then a simpler solution might be available since I am not a coder and this request pertains to my personal website.
I am also a brand new Google Anaylitics user.
Can I use the  tag attribute to track plays of songs on my website? If so, could someone please provide a coding example?
If not, what suggestion would you have for doing so (with coding examples).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you want to send to GA play events with parameters equal to audio tag id? If u're using standard (universal) GA (not implemented by Google Tag Manager) try for example code like this (assums that you use jquery; of course it can be changed to pure JS version):

```
$('audio').bind('play', function() {
   ga('send', 'event', 'Audio', $(this)[0].id, $(this)[0].currentSrc);
});
```

This code should bind to all audio tags on current URL function which sends google analytics event with player id attribute and audio source as event parameters when someone will play audio.